# git push and distributed workflows

Tags: git

Alice and Bob are trying to work on the same project. Here's what we've done so far.

Bob:

```
mkdir myproject
cd myproject
echo "Hello" > readme.txt
git init
git add readme.txt
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
```

Alice:

```
git init
git remote add bob ssh://bob/home/bob/projects/myproject
git pull bob
git checkout remote/bob/master -b bobsMaster
echo "Hello again" >> readme.txt
git add readme.txt
git commit -m "Improving readme"
git push bob bobsMaster
```

Now this is where we're stuck. The push succeeds but I have no idea where Alice's commit has gone. When Bob types `git log` from his `master` branch, Alice's commit is nowhere to be found.

Are we going about the distributed workflow in completely the wrong way? How should Alice and Bob work together on the same branch? Note that we have no central location to host our repos so we want to work entirely distributed.

**Edit:**

We're going to go with the pull only workflow as suggested. The reason we didn't spot the bobsMaster branch in Bob's repo is because we assumed that appeared from doing an earlier pull. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bob should have a `bobsMaster` branch created. If you want to push `bobsMaster` to Bob's `master` branch use this:

```
git push bob bobsMaster:master
```

In your workflow it's much better that Bob and Alice pull from other's repo, as pushing to a non-bare repo is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You pushed the changes to `bobsMaster` and not to `master`. Thus Bob must merge

```
git checkout master
git merge bobsMaster
```

Comment: Bob doesn't have a branch called bobsMaster. Are you suggesting that bob add Alice as a remote and merge from remote/alice/bobsMaster? If so, does that mean that Alice's push is unnecessary?

Comment: Nope, Alice _pushed_ `bobsMaster` into Bobs repository, thus after that it exists there. See CharlesBs answer. He pushed `bobsMaster:master`, which means, that he pushed the _local_ `bobsMaster` to the _remotes_ `master`. If you omit the remote branch name, git assumes `bobsMaster` => `bobsMaster:bobsMaster`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "missing commit":

```
git log --branches
```

should be enough for you to see Alice's commits (since they have been done in a different branch '`bobsMaster`' than yours '`master`')

Answer (score 1):

The commit was pushed to a new remote branch called `bobsMaster` in `bob` repository (the branch was created by `git push bob bobsMaster`).

The last argument in that command specifies remote refspec - if it's not found on the remote side, it's being created. `bob` repository had only one branch (`master`), so by pushing to `bobsMaster` you created that branch in Bob's repo.

You should use `git push bob master` to push your changes to Bob's master branch.